# Post only an image file OR allow post of no file

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a way in javascript to post alert if the file it is supposed to be posted is not an image **OR** to return true if no file is selected?

Comment: No, you can't know what file was selected, you can only know it's extension.

Comment: with the new javascript [FileReader API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filereader), you can actually read file type rather than just extension. [Here is a good rundown](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-open-dropped-files/). Keep in mind, [support for this is still thin (No IE until IE10!)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader).

Comment: My comment was more informational than helpful. Can you please specify the browser support you require? If you require IE, we can show you how to check against the file extension and only post if its in some list of image types (jpg, png, gif, etc.).

Comment: as lbstr has said your script in the browser will have to do the checking on the local file for you. And you can't trust the browser to run your script, so in the end you'd have to check it on your server anyway. If you're just checking for 'dumb' rather than malicious users then there are libraries available to parse image files.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236059/post-only-an-image-file-or-allow-post-of-no-file] @lbstr Thanks for the information

Comment: @lbstr Yes i require IE. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @bmaglar Can you show us what you have so far? We would just need to see the `form` and any javascript that you have for that form so far.

Comment: @lbstr <FORM ....>
...
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="fpa" value="13" onClick="clickFunction">13%<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="fpa" VALUE="23" CHECKED onClick="clickFunction">23%
<TEXTAREA NAME="item_desc" COLS=20 ROWS=4></TEXTAREA>
<input type='file' name='avatarfile' id='avatarfile' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="return checkExt();" /></FORM>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">function checkExt(){
     var filename = document.getElementById('avatarfile').value;
   var filelength = parseInt(filename.length) - 3;
     var fileext = filename.substring(filelength,filelength + 3);
    
     // Check file extenstion
     if (fileext.toLowerCase() != "gif" && fileext.toLowerCase() != "jpg" && fileext.toLowerCase() != "png" && fileext.toLowerCase() != "bmp") {
       alert ("Μπορείτε να αποθηκεύσετε μόνο αρχεία εικόνων με κατάληξη gif, jpg, jpeg, png και bmp.");
       return false;
     } else {
       return true;
     }
 }
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

The following worked fine.
On form submit php code

```
<?php

$fileType = $_FILES['avatarfile']['type'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && (($_FILES['avatarfile']['type'] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES['avatarfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES['avatarfile']['type'] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES['avatarfile']['type'] == "image/bmp") || ($_FILES['avatarfile']['type'] == "image/png") || $fileType == NULL))
{

$query="insert into ...)";
header('Location:something.php');
}
else { 
echo "The file you tried to upload is not an image";
}
?>
```